# Issue with bundle install in CentOs machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

I am getting the following error while running bundle install in CentOs machine.I am getting this issuw with i18n gem.

```
System.java: -2:in 'arraycopy': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
       from DefaultResolver.java:111:in 'makeTIme'
       from DefaultResolver.java:277:in 'create'
       from DefaultResolver.java:317:in 'handleScalar'
       from DefaultResolver.java:435:in 'orgHandler'
```

I didn't get this issue with Windows Machine, I am getting this error only with CentOS.
I have the following code in gemfile.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem "i18n","=0.6.1"
gem "activeresource","=3.2.13"
gem "activesupport","=3.2.13"
gem "multi_json","=1.0.3"
```

Could you please help us on this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was an issue in JRuby that has since been fixed: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5806